# Angular Child Component does not change values when parent values change

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

The parent component is getting data from another component(Home Component) via routerLink. It is then sending this data to the child component.
This works well for the first time.
There is a search bar in my header which is visible in the home component page as well as the page rendered by parent and child component. Upon clicking on a valid entry in the search bar, I pass the `id` and `category` params to parent again, however, only the parent component changes while the child remains the same as the earlier one.
How do I pass the values again to child without refreshing?

Parent Component HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1>{{id}}</h1>
  <h1>{{category}}</h1>
  <child-component [id] = "id" [category] = "category"> </child-component>
</body>
```

Parent Component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit ,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent-component.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  id : any
  category : any

ngOnInit() {
      this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params.get('id');
      this.category = params.get("media_type");})

//do other stuff
```

Child Component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit , Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: any;
  @Input() category: any;

//do other stuff
```

Comment: Are Id and Category reference types or primitive types? If those are primitives can you make it an exact type instead of any?

Comment: the components in Angular should **not** have "body" -the body is in the index.html- has you change the ChangeDetectionStrategy? if not, by defect, should work. check if you has any error in console